# If $\gcd(r,s)=1$, which numbers can be written as a linear combination $as+br$ with $a,b$ nonnegative?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I know if $gcd(r,s)=1$ then $1=as+bs$ for some intgers $a,b$. Here's what I want to know: which numbers can be written as $as+br$, if I am restricted to $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$?

To be more specific, I want to show that $rs-s+v$ (where $1\le v<s<r$) can be written in this form, where $a,b\in \mathbb{N}$.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is nearly the content of the [Coin Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) for two denominations, which just asks which is the largest integer which *cannot* be realized this way, and it turns that the answer (the "Frobenius Number" for $(r, s)$) is $rs - r - s$. This result reduces your problem to checking a finite number of cases, and in practice this is easy to do by hand for small $r$ and $s$.

**Edit** As an answer for the question added in an edit, for each target number $m := rs - s + v$ notice that the integers $m, m - s, \ldots, m - (r - 1)s$ are inequivalent modulo $s$, precisely because $\gcd(r, s) = 1$.

**Remark** Maybe surprisingly, no closed-form formula exists for the Frobenius number for three or more denominations, though it's completely procedural if tedious to work it out by hand.

Comment: Boy,I hope Melvyn Nathanson doesn't see I got stuck on this problem.Then again,it is 3 am past and my brain is only working at 20 percent............lol

Comment: Thank you!! Although, its funny. Who would have thought this cute problem would be useful for proving crazy things about Elliptive Curves. This helps tremendously, when I finish my proof you will get the answer for the question.

Comment: My proof related to Elliptive Curves fell short, but I found another approach. Also, Pete L. Clark published a paper a few years back with an explicit formula for the coin problem if the three denominations are co-prime and a working formula, albeit tedious and far from "closed-form", to find them in more general situations.